# PhaseScriptExecution [firebase_crashlytics]\ Crashlytics\ Upload\ Symbols

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I tried to use `firebase_crashlytics` in my flutter package.

So I download flutter package.

> flutter pub add firebase_crashlytics

Then I configure firebase configuration.

> flutterfire configure

Android simulator works fine.

But Xcode build keeps being failed in this step.

`PhaseScriptExecution [firebase_crashlytics]\ Crashlytics\ Upload\ Symbol`

Error message is this:
`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

When I search regarding this, people say to change from a to b in file:
`frameworks.sh`

a:

> source="$(readlink "${source}")"

b:

> source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

[image]

But I already have '-f` in there.

How to solve this issue?